# CouchDB-Lucene get distinct rows from search

Tags: lucene, indexing, couchdb, distinct, couchdb-lucene

I have duplicated rows in my Lucene's index and I whant to retreive only distinct datas with the search.

- I think that I can't build the index without the duplicated datas because they are not stored in the same CouchDB table (JSON document). But maybe I am missing something, and it's possible to test whether one element is already indexed or not before returning it from the index function.
- If not, is it possible to retreive only distinct values from an index which contains duplicated datas?

Regards, Mickaël

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB-Lucene does not currently support "DISTINCT" or deduplication.

Comment: So, I guess that my only option is to implement the distinct client side and hope that I have less ducplicated data than the limit parameter of my query. Thanks for all of your answers!